# Не работает PHP скрипт

Tags: php

Имеется скрипт для вставки записи. К моему несчастью он крашется(причина мне неизвестна) на куске кода **$count_tel=** и собственно там, где условие с переменной **$count_tel**, если я уберу логику с этой переменной, то он работает. В чем ошибка? SQL запрос - верный, проверил через консоль PHPmyadmin.

```
$count_tel = R::getCell("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `clients` WHERE `client_tel` = ? LIMIT 1",array($response["phone"]));

        if($deleter&&$service_time)
        {
          if($count_tel["count"]<4)
          {
            $error_control=R::exec("INSERT IGNORE INTO `clients` (`service`,`service_time`,`master`, `date`, `time`, `client_name`, `client_surename`, `client_tel`, `client_inst`,`IP`,`key_client`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", array(
            $service,
            $service_time,
            $master,
            $date,
            $time,
            $name,
            $surename,
            $response["phone"],
            $inst,
            $response["ip"],
            $response["ucaller_id"]
            ));
          }
          else
          {
          $array_error = array(
            '1' => 'Вы записаны уже на 4 места, пожалуйста, оставьте места и другим!');
            echo json_encode($array_error);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Сейчас мы угадаем что такое `R::getCell` и что внутри за код

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки, к сожелению мы не телепаты

Comment: @Kirzzz, Может вы хотя бы напиши ошибку которую выдаёт интерпретатор? А то Ванга в отпуске...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov это скрипт ORM системы RedBean, для выборки одной ячейки(поскольку мы хотим узнать количество встречающихся в БД одинаковых номеров)

Comment: Может нет такого индекса? `$count_tel["count"]`

Comment: @VadimPedchenko я все делаю криво и кисо, и поэтому доступа к ошибкам у меня нет, есть только информация о том что без этого куска кода все работает, а с ним - нет.

Comment: Включите вывод ошибок `php` ну или хотя бы сделайте `var_dump` для `$count_tel`

Comment: @Alpha, я же указал в SQL запросе "as count", следовательно есть

Comment: @Alpha вывод `var_dump` для `$count_tel` , если я правильно понял, дал `string(1) "0"`

Comment: @Kirzzz вот вам и ответ, у вас нет индекса `count` как я и написал выше

Comment: @Alpha как его может не быть, если в SQL запросе написано "as count"?

Comment: @Kirzzz ищите в документации к RedBeen что он возвращает, я с ним не работал

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка была действительно в том, что функция `R::getCell` возвращает исключительно клетку, без названия поля, следовательно указания имени поля `$count_tel["count"]` было не нужно.